# How to find specific array property ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs, nodemon

I am fairly new to ejs and javascript in general. In my ejs file, I am attempting to display a list of array objects, and these array objects each have their own properties. I am attempting to loop through the length of the array, and if the name of the specified property matches a string, I want to display the details property of the array. I tried a for loop but it is not printing anything, maybe a for each loop would be necessary?

```
<% for(var i=0; i<list.length; i++){ %>
    <% if(list.connectionName === 'hand') { %>
     <li> <%= list[i].details %> </li>
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace:

```
list.connectionName
```

with

```
list[i].connectionName
```

as `list` here is an array not an object.